# Utilising blank space

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am not sure if this is possible but anyways here it is.

Currently the stackoverflow page looks like this. There is lot of unused space on the left and right

[image]

Is it possible to put something useful in that space? For example, I would love to see the `top 5 series` as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

**Post discussions in comments.**

Alternatively we can have widgets so that users with higher resolution can opt in for them?

Comment: There might be 400px of whitespace on *your* screen, but not on mine (I have less than 190px there).  Don't assume everyone's running at huge resolutions in maximized browser windows.

Comment: @Charles: Hmm that is interesting. I have checked it on IE and Chrome as well. It is there for me in all the browsers/

Comment: That is because of your pixel density. The best approach is for you to zoom the page. Another approach would be for stackexchange to detect these large gaps and then zoom for you. However, placing content in there is kind of bad idea.

Comment: @SiddharthRout He's saying that not everyone uses the same screen size, and not everyone has the their window maximized. There are a *lot* of people out there who only keep their browser windows at half screen sized, and keep something else open on the other side of the screen.

Comment: @animuson: Yes I understood that. The comment was edited and I was actually replying to it...

Comment: @Travis: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Because for users who do not see that "blank space" their view will be disrupted.

Comment: @TravisJ Perhaps have widgets for people with higher resolutions then so that we can opt in for that?

Comment: I use that space for my post-it notes, you insensitive clod!

Comment: @JoshCaswell: lol then don't opt for the widgets. Apparently you didn't read my question correctly. You can choose which widget to apply ;)

Comment: @Josh was making a joke :-P

Comment: @Doorknob: I know and hence my comment started with `lol` ;)

Comment: What? Not everyone uses a 27" monitors to browse SO? Damn, you guys are so 2012 with your 21" monitors....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what my view of Stack Overflow looks like right now:

[image]

This is Chrome maximized on my laptop. Not much whitespace to work with at all.

Even if there *were* more space, I hesitate to put more and more information up. The focus of the page should be the questions. Add too much more on either side, and we'll end up too much like those other Q&A sites where it's hard to tell [what is even happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAw59.png).

As far as creating widgets goes, I don't hate the idea, but I also kinda like the relatively clean look we have now. On some devices I run with a higher resolution and more whitespace. On others, I'm really cramped for space. I think adding widgets would introduce more complexity and ultimately worse UX to the point where few would install them, in which case why are we even building them. :)

Granted, that's speculation. But considering how much work would have to go into adjusting the site design, defining which widgets would exist, building UI for managing them, etc. I'd like to be more sure that it's *probably* a good idea before we even start.

Comment: Thanks Anna. I just edited my question. Can we not have widgets? So that if I want to have them then I can opt for them. Zooming my FF screen really looks weird.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't hate the idea of widgets, but I also kinda like the relatively clean look we have now. On some devices I run with a higher resolution and more whitespace. On others, I'm really cramped for space. I think adding widgets would introduce more complexity and ultimately worse UX.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - You can always make a user script.

Comment: So I should assume that this suggestion will not be incorporated and close the question? :)

Comment: @TravisJ: Wish I knew how to write userscripts ;) I wouldn't have asked a question here :D

Comment: One quick clarification regarding what you said... `I think adding widgets would introduce more complexity and ultimately worse UX.` Are you referring from `Coding Perspective` or `UI Perspective` Because if it is UI then it really doesn't matter because if I don't like the look I will not install the widget.

Comment: @SiddharthRout UI. I think the experience will be bad for people who install the widgets to the point where few would install them, in which case why are we even building them. :) Granted, that's speculation. But considering how much work would have to go into adjusting the site design, defining which widgets would exist, building UI for managing them, etc. I'd like to be more sure that it's *probably* a good idea before we even start.

Comment: `I'd like to be more sure that it's probably a good idea before we even start.` By looking at the downvotes, I already feel that no one wants to have that widget so I guess I will rest my case. :) Request you to please add the text from your last comment to your answer because that is what exactly answers my query and also so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout done :)

Comment: Thank You and Much appreciated for taking out time to reply to my questions rather than just downvoting from the sidelines ;)